# Convert UTC time to specific zone

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following data:

var currentTime: 2013-07-11 15:55:36+00:00
var currentTimezone: Africa/Asmera

I need a way to convert the currentTime in UTC to a new time based on currentTimezone.

I've looked into [Timezone.js](https://github.com/mde/timezone-js) and I'm having trouble implementing it (the directions on the site are a little ambiguous)

The code for the function I'm intending on using is included. Thanks :)

```
    <script>

    $("#storeTime").click(function(){
        storeCurrentTime();
    })

    $("#getTime").click(function(){
        retrieveTime();
    })

    $("#storeTimezone").click(function(){
        var yourTimezone = $('#timezone-select').find(":selected").text();
        tz = yourTimezone.toString();
        storeCurrentTimezone(tz);
    })

    $("#convertTime").click(function(){
        //get the most recent UTC time, clean it up
        var currentTime = $('#RetrievedTime').html();
        currentTime = currentTime.split(": ")[1];
        $('#convertedTime').html("Converted Time: " + currentTime);     

        //get the saved timezone
        var currentTimezone = $('#storedTimezone').html();

    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need to know the timezone offset, so some sort of dictionary with strings to numbers.

```
// assuming your dictionary says 3 hours is the difference just for example.
var timezoneDiff = 3;
```

Then you can just make a new time like this

```
// Assuming you have the proper Date string format in your date field.
var currentDate = new Date(currentTime);
// Then just simply make a new date.
var newDate = new Date(currentDate.getTime() + 60 * 1000 * timezoneDiff);
```

**Update**

I've written a javascript helper for this which you can find at:
http://heuuuuth.com/projects/OlsonTZConverter.js

I pulled the timezone data from the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Usage is as follows once included the script.

```
var offset = OlsonTZConverter.GetUTCOffset("Africa/Asmera");
```

or if there is Daylight Savings in effect:

```
var offset = OlsonTZConverter.GetUTCOffset("Africa/Asmera",true);
```

These will throw if you pass an invalid timezone, but you can check if a timezone is valid with:

```
var isValid = OlsonTZConverter.Contains("Africa/Asmera");
```

or just look at the entire dictionary with:

```
var tzDict = OlsonTZConverter.ListAllTimezones();
```

Hope this maybe saves someone some time sometime :).

Comment: While this is an option, I have a list of Olson timezones but this list doesn't contain any offset information. I was hoping to find a way to do it using only the timezone string.

Comment: It would be horrible to make such a dictionary if the list is *all* the timezones, and I agree about directions for Timezone.js I can't make sense of it either, there must be a library for this..

Comment: I realize this is quite late and you've probably worked something out by now but I've been busy with other things. I made a little javascript helper class for this very thing since I figure other people may have the same problem and not want to go to the effort of making the dictionary either. Updating above with usage.